# Laravel get result toSql in QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `select` method of laravel QB and I want to get `MYSql` command of that's created.

Laravel QB:

```
public function scopeiOS( $query ){
    $result = $query->select( DB::raw('count(`platform`) as iOS' ) )     ->where( 'platform' , '=', 'iOS' )      ->pluck('iOS');
}
```

`toSql()` is not member of that function.

Comment: $result is not a query builder object. post the whole code.

Comment: @itachi that's not my problem

Comment: that actually is your problem because `toSql()` is a method attributed to QueryBuilder object only.... none the less, with this rude attitude, good luck getting an answer from others too.

Comment: I don't see `toSql()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `toSql()` but if you want to get the query created then you might want to look at the logs of the queries executed for that request.

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

Or get the last query executed:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

Or maybe (warning untested code)

```
public function scopeiOS( Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query ){
    $result = $query->select( DB::raw('count(`platform`) as iOS' ) )
                    ->where( 'platform' , '=', 'iOS' )
                    ->pluck('iOS');
}
```

Check [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) for more information on `toSql()`.

```
/**
 * Get the SQL representation of the query.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function toSql()
{
    return $this->grammar->compileSelect($this);
}
```